# Python Send Keys Function In Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I m trying to send keys using selenium by send keys function to fill some data but unfortunately code is not working.Here is HTML CODE where i want to fill some data and Python selenium code below.What can be the problem in my code

```
<input type="text" style="margin-bottom:16px" value="My New Sketch" autocomplete="on" maxlength="60" minlenght="2" required="required" class="required" tabindex="1" name="title">
```

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".required").send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".required").send_keys("UserName");
    time.sleep(8)
```

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: Here is that input field where i want to fill data http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONOYdb

Comment: Usually, when I find that an element I am trying to access and fill out isn't getting the expected input, it is because there is another element on the page that came before the expected element.  Is it possible that you have another element on the page that would match ".required"?  Also, "not working" isn't quite descriptive enough. Are you getting errors in the code or are you just not seeing the text in the input?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why back space is used here but to clear input fields can use clear, in java

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".required")).clear();
```

if sendkeys does not works, some time initial click then sendkeys work well

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".required")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".required")).sendKeys("data here");
```

I hope required wait is provided.

Thank You,
Murali